# JS Star rating how to get <span> value for MYSQL?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

Source: [GitHub Dobtco starrr JS plugin](https://github.com/dobtco/starrr)

Using this plugin for the user to review company in different fields & Store the data on MySQL database.

**Updated:** I edited the javascript file to use the star for 2 different review fields for multiple use.

**Coding part:** Updated with K Scandrett

```
<form method="post" name="review" action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
  <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
<div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group">
    Review 1: <div id="stars_1" class="starrr" name ="rv_1" data-rating=<?php echo $rv_1 ?> ></div>  
    You gave a rating of <span id="count">0</span> star(s)
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="rv_1" name="rv_1" value="2" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
    Review 2: <div id="stars_2"  class="starrr" name ="rv_2" data-rating=<?php echo $rv_2 ?>></div>  
    You gave a rating of <span id="count_2">0</span> star(s)
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="rv_2" name="rv_2" value="4" />
        </div>
  </div>
      <input type="hidden" value="<?php $user_id ?>" name ="user_id_review"/>
      <input type="hidden" value="<?php $company_id ?>" name ="company_id"/>
      <div class="panel-footer"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="review">Save</button></div>
  </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read/update the `input` use [`val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/).

When you read/update the `span` use [`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) (unless it contains HTML that you want to include).

Note: you're missing the `echo` command in `value="<?php $user_id ?>"` and `value="<?php $company_id ?>`.

```js
$(function() {

  var $s1Input = $('#rv_1');
  var $s2Input = $('#rv_2');

  $('#stars_1').starrr({
    rating: $s1Input.val(),
    change: function(e, value) {
      $('#count').text(value);
      $s1Input.val(value);
    }
  });

  $('#stars_2').starrr({
    rating: $s2Input.val(),
    change: function(e, value) {
      $('#count_2').text(value);
      $s2Input.val(value);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.starrr {
  display: inline-block;
}

.starrr a {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FFD119;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://dobtco.github.io/starrr/dist/starrr.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  Review 1:
  <div id="stars_1" class="starrr"></div>
  You gave a rating of <span id="count">0</span> star(s)
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rv_1" name="rv_1" value="2" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  Review 2:
  <div id="stars_2" class="starrr"></div>
  You gave a rating of <span id="count_2">0</span> star(s)
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rv_2" name="rv_2" value="4" />
</div>
```

Comment: It's not necessary to read the value from the span if you write it directly to the hidden input field at the same time as setting the span's value. (although I've made it visible in the demo, you can change the input to `type="hidden"`)

Comment: running this code snippet shows error with the inbuild StackOverflow coding section.

Comment: It may be because I referenced `http://dobtco.github.io/starrr/dist/starrr.js`, without using `https`.  I'll update my answer....

Comment: chrome, Plus the using your coding it didn't work mysql is not getting any value from  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="rv_1" name="rv_1" />

Comment: By default when user logs in user see what rating he have given in past, that I show with data-rating=<?php echo $rv_2 ?> part no problem there. But if user again update his rating then its not getting value obviously because input type doesn't have any 'value' field and I have no idea how to get that from span

Comment: I've updated my answer. Now it will set the initial value from the value in the input (which you can set with `value="<?php echo $rv_2 ?>"`).

Comment: There is no 'name' at the input type so how I am going to call it $_POST['rv_1'] ?

Comment: Good point, I'll add it back. I removed it because you had it set twice - once on the div and once on the input.  You only want name on the input.

Comment: <span id="count">0</span> this part is not working now. not showing as it shows for count_2. I have tested your new code but mysql is still not getting anything

Comment: Works in Chrome for me. Are you sure you don't have a typo

Comment: yes spans are working not but the main problem is still in there. mysql is not updating. do you want me to be post php mysql part of coding?

Comment: echo $r_1; part is showing correct user selected rating but it's not just updating the database now.

Comment: Have you checked at all 4 posted vars are set, and that it is trying to execute the body of the `if` statement?

Comment: Also I'd check the where clause - it might not be matching the record you expect it will

Comment: Ok did the debugging. Following part is not working  <input type="hidden" value="<?php $user_id ?>" name ="user_id_review" />
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php $company_id ?>" name ="company_id" /> So that it $_POST['user_id_review'],$_POST['company_id'] can receive any values But individually $user_id & $company_id is working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151812/discussion-between-k-scandrett-and-mimi).

Comment: Hi There is a problem with the showing existing star rating , original code has an option like this   $('#stars-existing').on('starrr:change', function(e, value){
    $('#count-existing').html(value);
  }); which I use to show average rate from all users. How to implement that? that part needs to be readonly.